# naming convention explanation for java to xml and java to json jar

Tags: java, spring-mvc, jackson, jaxb2

i am curious to understand what would be the reason to name

java to xml conversion jar as jaxb2

and

java to json conversion jar as jackson

I tried searching for some history/explanation for this name. But not successful.

Would be good to know about the name reasons for better understanding.

Thanks for reading

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about etymology of library names, not a programming problem.

Comment: They're named that way because that's how whoever made them chose to name them. Ask the authors of those libraries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JAXB is abbreviation from [Java Architecture for XML Binding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Architecture_for_XML_Binding)

Jackson is simply a [Jackson name](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jackson_%28name%29)

Answer (score 1):

JAXB is a JCP specification  (JSR-222) and stands for Java Arcitecture for XML binding.  The name JAXB is consistent with other XML related JSRs: JAXP, JAX-WS, etc.  JAXB isn't an implementation but a standard API.  Implementations of JAXB have their own names:  Project JAXB, MOXy, JaxMe.

Jackson is the name of a JSON binding library.  There are other JSON binding libraries in Java such as:  MOXy, GSON, Genson, XStream.